# Looking for Python module for graph visualization

Tags: python-3.x, graph-theory

I'm looking for a python 3 module that can generate a visual representation of a graph. Ideally I would give it a list of nodes and a list of connection, as well as some small amount of data associated with those things, and it would open a window (but an image saved on disk is fine) showing said nodes connected as specified. I don't want to specify the positions of the nodes, instead I'd like the software to arrange them in a way that minimizes edge crossings at least approximately.

Is there any such module? All I've been able to find are plotters and such...

If there is none, an easy-to-learn graphics module would do: I have never done any graphics things.

Comment: **See:** https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/

Comment: Oh. How did I miss it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html). It offers the possibility to [draw graphs with matplotlib](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs)